# cv2 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with opencv in my last study's project. I have python 2.7 and opencv 3.4 already installed. I developed my python project in windows 8 64 bit and I converted my application from .py to .exe through Pyinstaller and it's working fine .

But when I move my application to the industrial machine which is windows xp pack 3 32bit and i try to import cv2 I get the following error :

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Note that I have tried to install Microsoft visual c++ 2015 and didn't solve the problem .

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is the version of python on the industrial machine 32-bit? Same with the opencv version?

Comment: i'm using opencv x86 and python 2.7 32 bits and it's working on my computer (windows 8 x64) but it doesn't work on the industrial machine (window xp 32 bits)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I solved it by placing two dlls in the same folder as my .exe file. The dlls are "api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll" which can be downloaded from the internet and other one is "opencv_ffmpeg***_**.dll" which can be found in python site-packages if you have installed python-opencv via pip, where *** is the version and ** is 32 or 64 bit. After you have gathered these two files, compile the script using following options.

```
pyinstaller -w script.py
```

Now place the two dlls in dist/your_folder/ where the .exe is located. Also be careful of all the warnings related to missing dlls while compiling, if you see any warning related to missing dlls, place that dll in .exe folder afterward.

Comment: Hello @adeelz92!  I added following 2 dlls into my exe file. But still not works, btw how do you know missing dlls while comliing?

Answer (score 0):

Which version using for build opencv?

- Try install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145) for your version.
- Try rebuild dll for Windows XP 32 bit

Comment: how can i know that the version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio it compatible for my version of opencv or not ?

Comment: Are you install opencv on Windows XP?
Are you install https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145 ?

Comment: yes they are already installed and i didn't solve the problem

Comment: "how can i know that the version..." -- Either you built it yourself and presumably know which tool you used, or you downloaded the official distribution, where the binaries are in a subdirectory titled something like "vc14" which identifies the version of MSVC++ it was built with and intended to be used with.